# qgis-processing: how to specify optional outputs?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

Suppose a script has a variable number of outputs, which may or may not be produced depending on settings:

```
##Input_layer=vector
##Output_1=output vector
##Produce_output_2=boolean
##Output_2=output vector

from qgis.core import *

def create_my_output(path):
    # whatever...

create_my_output(Output_1)

if Produce_output_2:
    create_my_output(Output_2)
```

If this script is run with "Produce output 2" unchecked then QGIS displays a warning dialog saying Output 2 was not correctly produced, even though not producing Output 2 was clearly intended behaviour.

Is there a way to tell QGIS that an output is optional?

Comment: What about replacing `if Produce_output_2:` with `if Produce_output_2 == True`? Then after your `create_my_output(Output_2)`, use `else: pass`.

Comment: what would `else: pass` do - isn't that effectively a null operation?

Comment: Effectively yes although I may have misunderstood your question. I assumed that checking "Produce output 2", you _want_ to create an optional output; unchecking it, you _don't want_ the optional output. Hopefully others can advise :)

Comment: That's correct.  The dialog is not generated by the `if` statement though, it's generated by QGIS looking for an output that's not there if the conditional doesn't get run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First alternative:

You could uncheck the ***Open output file after running algorithm*** option if you uncheck `Produce output 2`.

As you mentioned in your comment, QGIS cannot load this output if it doesn't get processed by the algorithm, therefore disabling the option to load it should work without an error message showing up.

---

### Second alternative:

Use `output file` instead of `output vector` for "Output_2". QGIS will not load this immediately if processed, which means you can add `runandload` into the algorithm. And if it's not processed, QGIS will not make a fuss. I made a simple buffer script using your definitions:

```
##Input_layer=vector
##Output_1=output vector
##Output_2=output file
##Produce_output_2=boolean

processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", Input_layer, 0.01, 10, False, Output_1)

if Produce_output_2 == True:
    processing.runandload("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", Input_layer, 1.00, 10, False, Output_2)
else:
    pass
```

Hope this helps somewhat!

Comment: Alas not an alternative if you're trying to make an easy to use UI for somebody else.  Unless there's a way to uncheck that from your python script?

Comment: @SideshowBob - Haven't found out how to uncheck this from the python script but I'm sure there's a way :)

Comment: @SideshowBob - Couldn't find how to uncheck the "Open output file..." option through the script but added another alternative :)